# Contact Import German Date Format support?

Tags: contacts, import, dates

CiviCRM 5.20.2/WP:

My system is using german locale. The contact import does not offer german date format "dd.mm.yyyy", even it is set for birth class in the date settings (dd.mm.yy).

How can I get german date format dd.mm.yyyy supported in the contact importer?

The contact import page only offers these date formats:

- yyyy-mm-dd OR yyyymmdd
- mm/dd/yy OR mm-dd-yy
- mm/dd/yyyy OR mm-dd-yyyy
- Month dd, yyyy
- dd/mm/yy
- dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, the easiest way is, to open the csv in Excel (or LibreCalc) and do some magic with formulas?

Something like

`=SUBSTITUTE(C9;".";"/")`

Or even much easier: Open the file in Excel (or LibreCalc) and do some search and replace in the column?

That's the way I would do it, if the file isn't to big for Excel and it isn't a work I had to do every day.

Comment: I think there is a simpler workaround of just changing the format of the dates to dd/mm/yyyy then saving as csv